# Inhumane changing condiions

Tags: united-kingdom, human-rights, school

In the school that I go to, we are occasionally (around 10 times a year) having to suffer inhumane changing conditions. There are 4 average sized groups and half the changing room is covered by desks and chairs for storage. Today, I physically couldn't get to my changing space without climbing over un-sturdy chairs which is a safety risk. There are 2-3 students per square meter. The air is also full of deodorant and is a risk for asthma attacks, the room is also full of Carbon Dioxide. We were so squashed we felt like animals in a cage in a zoo. When we were changing the second time I had to wait for two people to change to get to my space.

Can I report the school and is this a violation of Human Rights?

Comment: Check your local building code for occupancy and safety regulations. Most public spaces have a limit on "max occupancy" for safety reasons. The local fire department may be more helpful here than the United Nations, so I wouldn't go the "human rights" violation path just now.

Comment: Carbon dioxide is not much of a problem usually, as it is chemically inert (it is carbon monoxide that is poisonous). I mean, you would suffocate in an atmosphera that only has CO2, but only because it lacks oxygen. But you really need a lot of CO2 to reduce oxygen content to risky levels, and you won't get that out of human respiration unless you hermetically seal the room for a very long time.

Comment: @SJuan76 Actually carbon dioxide _is_ poisonous and can kill without suffocating you. Unlike truly inert gases like dinitrogen (air is 70% of that stuff anyway), a mere 5% concentration of carbon dioxide will kill you very quickly. Of course, being in a cramped room isn't going to raise the levels anywhere close to dangerous...